# I FUBAR'd the IP, subnet, and VLAN settings. Now how to access managed switch?

Tags: routing, switch, subnet, vlan

I have a Dell powerconnect 2748. I think I have done messed it up though when setting it up because so far I have not been able to access the webconfig of the switch after I changed some settings I shouldn't have. Here's all of the configurations that I can remember:

> - ports 1 & 2 are set as a LAG group and the LAG group is an untagged member of VLAN 2 with a PVID = 2 on both ports
> - ports 3-24 are untagged members of VLAN 2 with PVID = 2 on all
> - ports 25-44 are untagged members of VLAN 3 with PVID = 3 on all ports
> - ports 45-47 are untagged members of VLAN 1 with PVID = 1 on all ports
>     (Default settings)
> - port 48 is tagged member of VLAN 1, 2, and 3 with PVID = 1

The last thing I did was set the switch's IP address. I set it to the following:

```
IP: 192.168.254.2
Subnet: 255.255.255.252
Gateway: 192.168.254.1
```

My goal was to create a subnet that only contained the switch's IP and the router's IP. I thought the /30 subnet would only allow 2 routable address: 2^(32-30) = 4, 1 network address, 1 broadcast address, and 2 host addresses. However, now no matter what I do, I cannot connect back the the switch's webconfig. I have set my laptop's NIC to `192.168.254.1` and tried every port on the switch but it fails to connect to the web config.

Can anyone help me with the settings needed to get access back to the webconfig of the switch?

Comment: Which VLAN has the subnet of the switch? That VLAN needs to extend from the switch to the router, and the router needs to have the gateway address configured on its end of the VLAN.

Comment: @RonMaupin - I don't know. I haven't been able to figure that out. I didn't change any of the settings for ports 45-47, those are the default settings.

Comment: This sort of thing is done all the time. I don't know about this switch specifically, but I would guess that the management address thinks it's on VLAN 1. In any case, you need a VLAN on which that subnet is assigned, and the VLAN needs to go to a router with the corresponding gateway address in the subnet as the address on the VLAN. You can only get from one VLAN or subnet to another through a router.

Comment: Have you tried resetting the switch and starting over?

Comment: @davidpostill, I'm trying to avoid resetting the switch, I'd like to try to learn how to fix it (if it can be) before taking the easy way out and just resetting it.